# Add SSL certificates in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, ssl-certificate

I have a web application which tries to hit a https url. I have a set of 4 certificates which I import in one common file using keytool

```
keytool -import -v -alias a_base64 -trustcacerts -file a_Base64.cer -keystore testcacerts
keytool -import -v -alias b_base64 -trustcacerts -file b_base64.cer -keystore testcacerts
keytool -import -v -alias c_base64 -trustcacerts -file c_Base64.cer -keystore testcacerts
keytool -import -v -alias d_base64 -trustcacerts -file d_base64.cer -keystore testcacerts
```

The file testcacerts is generated fine. In my eclipse IDE, I have a java program that will hit the https url. While running the program, I gave the following in the VM arguments
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=c://testcacerts

The java program ran fine. Now I am deploying the war of the project in tomcat server 7. When my application tries to access https url, it gives the following exception

```
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

I set the environment variables CATALINA_OPTS and JAVA_OPTS to point to that testcacerts location
    JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/temp/testcacerts

After I re start my tomcat, when my application hits the https url, am getting the same exception.
I even tried to change the configuration in server.xml in tomcat conf as given below

```
   <Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" 
maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" 
scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"  
keystoreFile="/temp/testcacerts" keystorePass="samplePassword" />
```

The password in keystorePass is the one that I gave while generating the keystore.

Even after the above changes, I was getting the same exception.

I am currently running the application in Unix environment and the tomcat is present in Unix server as well. I don't have access to the java installation directory and because of which I am not able to place this certificate file in the jre\lib\security folder.

Am I missing anything here. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it is valid self-signed certificates you should select one certificate for the SSL connector. Please add `keyAlias` with the selected certificate (e.g. `a_base64`) to your connector configuration

```
<Connector port="8443" ... keyAlias="a_base64" />
```

Usefull links:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

You may remove your `-Djavax` settings.

Comment: Hi Micheal, Thanks for the suggestions. I removed the javax settings and then tried giving the keyAlias. This time while starting the tomcat I got the following exception "Alias name a_base64 does not identify a key entry" . I tried adding a private key entry to the testcacerts file "keytool -genkey -keystore testcacerts -alias privKey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048". Now in the keyAlias i gave the value "privKey". This time around I didn't get any exception during startup but still the old exception "unable to find valid certification path to requested target." exists. Can you please me?

Comment: please try to create self signed certificate as explained in the first link above. Note that by default alias is `tomcat`

Comment: I mean pls move step by step: 1. self signed according to site 2. change alias 3. change keysize

Comment: Did you try it? You can accepts and promote my answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Hi Micheal, I set the CATALINA_OPTS to point to that certificate file in the catalina.sh file. Now it was working fine. Gave the following "JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/temp/testcacerts". Thanks a lot for your help Micheal. And sorry for the late update.